# Firefox: Automatically paste links into my currently open text editor

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Is there a Firefox plugin that allows the user to press a keyboard shortcut and automatically have:

1) all links on the currently visible web page copied to the clipboard for pasting into a text editor;

2) all DOM nodes matching the results of a jquery expression copied to the clipboard for  pasting into a text editor;

3) the external text editor launched automatically after doing 1 or 2 above;

If there is not a specific plugin that does this, do you know of a general purpose plugin that can be extended to emulate this functionality (for example, can you do it with Vimperator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [Copy Links add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/605) to achieve your first requirement. [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12632) may be able to help you with the second. Number 3 can be done with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com).

I don't know of an add-on that does all of this in one though.