# Select block of text in webpage, paste link addresses

Tags: browser, browser-addons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to easily copy hyperlinks in web pages](https://superuser.com/questions/306499/how-to-easily-copy-hyperlinks-in-web-pages)

I'm looking for a way in any web browser (Chrome is my preference) where I can select a block of text, which might contain links, and then when I copy the text and paste it into a text editor, instead of (or in addition to) the link text being pasted, the link address is. Does anyone know of an extension or something that can do this?

Comment: Possible Dupe: [How to easily copy hyperlinks in web pages](http://superuser.com/questions/306499/how-to-easily-copy-hyperlinks-in-web-pages) perhaps also see [Include the URL of all hyperlinks in the document's text](http://superuser.com/questions/385992/include-the-url-of-all-hyperlinks-in-the-documents-text) and [Firefox: Automatically paste links into my currently open text editor](http://superuser.com/questions/86523/firefox-automatically-paste-links-into-my-currently-open-text-editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you copy from Internet Explorer 8 into Microsoft Word 2007, links are pasted as Word hyperlinks.